# Change value of c_ulong() in other class

Tags: python, ctypes, python-unittest

I have a file ConnectToBoard.dll which is using to communication with a hardware and in my test framework I write a wrapper for send command from framework to devices.

I need create a unit test for this wrapper, which will be use a ConnectToBoard.dll without physical hardware - I create a class in python which will be return the same value like return ConnectToBoard.dll but without logic code of this library (just hardcoded value). For example:

wrapper_framework.py

```
class WrapperFramework():
    def __init__(self, test_mode=False):
        self.dll = WinDLL(ConnectToBoard.dll)
        if test_mode:
           self.dll = MockForConnectToBoard()

    def open_com_port(self):
        return self.dll.OpenComPort()
```

In dll are method which will be looking a free com port and return a name port in string. In my unit test I want created sth like this:

unittest.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def setup_wrapper()
    return WrapperFramework(test_mode=True)

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('setup_wrapper')
class TestMain:
      def test_open_com_port():
          assert setup_wrapper.dll.open_com_port == 'COM1'
```

mock_for_connect_to_board.py

```
class MockForConnectToBoard()
      def OpenComPort():
          return 'COM1'
```

But I have a problem with ctypes in python with my mock. I don't know what I should do in this situation:
wrapper_framework.py

```
def get_version_connect_to_board(self):
    major = c_ulong()
    minor = c_ulong()
    build = c_ulong()
    self.dll.GetVersionConnectToBoard(byref(major), byref(minor), byref(build))
    return f'{major.value}.{minor.value}.{build.value}'
```

unittest.py

```
    major = c_ulong()
    minor = c_ulong()
    build = c_ulong()
    setup_wrapper.dll.GetVersionConnectToBoard(byref(major), byref(minor), byref(build))
    assert major.value == 1
    assert minor.value == 1
    assert build.value == 1
```

(yep, it works for normal .dll without test mode and with physical devices)
And now: I don't know how I should write method GetVersionConnectToBoard in my mock. I tried sth like this:

mock_for_connect_to_board.py

```
def GetVersionConnectToBoard(self, major, minor, build):
    major.value = 1
    minor.value = 1
    build.value = 1
    return major, minor, build
```

But I have error:

```
AttributeError: 'CArgObject' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I check type both variable - major in wrapper_framework.py and it is:

```
<class 'ctypes.c_ulong'>
```

but in mock_for_connect_to_board.py it is

```
<class 'CArgObject'>
```

How can I change value for major, minor and build in mock? Maybe is better way for this than create a mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
    major = c_ulong()
    minor = c_ulong()
    build = c_ulong()
    setup_wrapper.dll.GetVersionConnectToBoard(byref(major), byref(minor), byref(build))
```

It's because `ctypes.byref` creates a `CArgObject` instance from which you can't get the value: it's only meant to be passed to a C function.

Example:

```
def foo(param):
    print(param)

i = ctypes.c_int32(42)
foo(ctypes.byref(i))
```

This will print:

```
<cparam 'P' (00000266E652E490)> <class 'CArgObject'>
```

Fortunately you can use [`ctypes.pointer`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.pointer) (note: **lowercase** `pointer` not to be confused with `ctypes .POINTER`) to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
def foo(param):
    print(param, type(param))
    print(param.contents.value)
    # note: you can also change the value here
    # param.contents.value = 12

i = ctypes.c_int32(42)
foo(ctypes.pointer(i))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_c_long object at 0x000001CD108EE848> <class '__main__.LP_c_long'>
42
```

Note that you can access the parameter value by using `param.contents.value`.

If I'm not mistaken, your code should work with the following:

```
    major = c_ulong()
    minor = c_ulong()
    build = c_ulong()
    setup_wrapper.dll.GetVersionConnectToBoard(ctypes.pointer(major), ctypes.pointer(minor), ctypes.pointer(build))
```

Comment: Yep, it's work for my unittest for mock - but I have other question - what if I want a create unit test for wrapper_framework.py ? I can not change byref to pointer in wrapper_framework.py file - I can edit file mock_for_connect_to_board.py.